# How to find all link local ipv6 devices on a certain interface?

Tags: ipv6, multicast, link-local

We have a setup where a program on a linux server controls its linux subordinates (talks to them via TCP and UDP).

There are several groups of subordinates. Each group is connected via ethernet to a single network interface card on the server.

It is important to tell the groups apart.

Subordinates can go missing (they get broken), and should be hot-pluggable (broken ones are replaced with new ones and the server should see them within a minute or so).

Typically we will have only few subordinates (1-5).

What is the best practice to do such discovery?

My first attempt was to simply ping and filter the result via

```
ping6 ff02::1%wlp3s0
```

but only the server itself is answering. Strangely it works on my android tablet, and wireshark also sees ping replies from the other devices, but there is nothing in the ping output. I can ping unicast though. (I tested on my mint notebook, but why would it be reliable on the ubuntu server if it's not on the test machine? Can it depend on the nic driver? i've had issues with the wifi sometimes.)

I also had attempts with sending a multi cast udp package (is that even possible?), but it wasn't successful even locally:

```
// terminal a:
$ nc -6luv 10000
Listening on [:::] (family 10, port 10000)

//terminal b:
$ echo "blah" | nc -6uv "ff01::1%wlp3s0" 10000
nc: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
$ echo "blah" | nc -6uv -q1 "ff02::1%wlp3s0" 10000
Connection to ff02::1%wlp3s0 10000 port [udp/*] succeeded! // nothing on terminal a
```

Any other ideas?

Somebody said in the comments it could be ip6tables rules. I didn't change the default linux mint rules, output of ip6tables is here: It's quite long and I have little experience with reading it. Any help?

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw6-before-logging-input  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-before-input  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-after-input  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-after-logging-input  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-reject-input  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-track-input  all      anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw6-before-logging-forward  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-before-forward  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-after-forward  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-after-logging-forward  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-reject-forward  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-track-forward  all      anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw6-before-logging-output  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-before-output  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-after-output  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-after-logging-output  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-reject-output  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-track-output  all      anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw6-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  udp      anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  udp      anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  tcp      anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  tcp      anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  udp      anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:dhcpv6-client
ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  udp      anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:dhcpv6-server

Chain ufw6-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all      anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw6-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all      anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw6-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all      anywhere             anywhere             rt type:0
ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp packet-too-big
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp echo-reply
ufw6-user-forward  all      anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw6-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all      anywhere             anywhere             rt type:0
ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw6-logging-deny  all      anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
DROP       all      anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp packet-too-big
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp echo-reply
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp router-solicitation HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp router-advertisement HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp neighbour-solicitation HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp neighbour-advertisement HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 141 HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 142 HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 130
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 131
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 132
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 143
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 148 HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 149 HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 151 HL match HL == 1
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 152 HL match HL == 1
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 153 HL match HL == 1
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp echo-reply
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 144
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 145
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 146
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 147
ACCEPT     udp      fe80::/10            fe80::/10            udp spt:dhcpv6-server dpt:dhcpv6-client
ACCEPT     udp      anywhere             ff02::fb             udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp      anywhere             ff02::f              udp dpt:1900
ufw6-user-input  all      anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw6-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all      anywhere             anywhere             rt type:0
ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp packet-too-big
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp router-solicitation HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp neighbour-advertisement HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp neighbour-solicitation HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp router-advertisement HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 141 HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 142 HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 130
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 131
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 132
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 143
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 148 HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 149 HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 151 HL match HL == 1
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 152 HL match HL == 1
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 153 HL match HL == 1
ufw6-user-output  all      anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw6-logging-allow (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all      anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw6-logging-deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all      anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
LOG        all      anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw6-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all      anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw6-skip-to-policy-input (6 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all      anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw6-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw6-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp      anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp      anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain ufw6-user-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp      anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports 1714:1764
ACCEPT     tcp      anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports 1714:1764

Chain ufw6-user-limit (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all      anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
REJECT     all      anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable

Chain ufw6-user-limit-accept (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw6-user-logging-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-user-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-user-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-user-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I tried to disable the ufw firewall by `sudo ufw disable` and ping started to work. I'll report a bug with ubuntu soon, but is ping even a good way to do it?

Comment: yes, you are right. I was testing without the echo (and the -v) before. I got an error message now, and an success message, but still nothing on terminal a. -- erm, there was a comment about a missing pipe before.

Comment: Your `ping6` command should work. Could it be that you have some `ip6tables` rules that break it? I just tested these slightly different arguments on my LAN and got responses from 5 different devices: `ping6 -nc2 ff02::1%wlan0`

Comment: uhm, it can very well be. would also explain why it worked on the tablet. however, why would the default rules not allow it? anyway, i updated the question with the output of ip6tables -L. But i have little experience with it and don't want to break security of my laptop.

Comment: That output does not tell the full story. If you want the full story look at the output of `ip6tables-save`. What I can tell you about your firewall rules is that they look overly complicated. I have previously seen rules generated by `ufw` and they did not look very good. You are probably better off writing firewall rules by hand than using `ufw`.

Comment: well, and it is also not your job to debug ufw. At first i didn't even realise it is additional software. I'll report a bug to them. If you formulate the comment as an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on a LEDE firewall; link-local multicast pings (e.g. to ff02::1) were not answered because the echo replies were dropped by an output rule for ctstate INVALID. Unicast pings (link-local and ULA) worked fine.

I suspect that the conntrack system is missing a trick here - since the request's (multicast) destination is different from the reply's (unicast) source, it doesn't recognize them as related - though it should.